# Correct maven goals for copying resources to jar using with multiple pom files?

Tags: xml, maven

I have a large project with its own pom.xml.  I want to use either profiles or external "pom" files (which seems simpler) to copy some of the project's files into a different jar than the larger project's.  While aspects of what I want to do have documentation everywhere (including maven resource's plugin pages), some of even the simplest steps are skipped.

This is vt2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.joe</groupId>
    <artifactId>validateJoe</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mvnrepo</id>
            <name>Global Maven</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>com.joe.rules</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I must be misunderstanding maven goals because

mvn -fvt2.xml resources:process-resources

cannot find goal process-resources; what command line do I want to execute copying resources?

Comment: Your configuration using `mvnrepository.com` as a repository is simply wrong, cause mvnrepository is no Maven repository...Apart from that I don't understand your question? Usually a resource is located under `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` which is copied by default within the appropriate location like `target/classes` or `target/test-classes`...Furthermore resources should be kept within a project/module...Based what I can see a directory `com.joe.rules` where are those things located? And what kind of files do you like to use ?

Comment: Thanks! I will remove mvnrepository.com - that was added when files in the central repository were not making it into my larger application - so I tried to declare maven central repository explicitly.  My goal is to put only files from some directories under src/main/resources into the jar files, whereas the larger project puts them all.  Is using the pom from my larger project but with exclude or include filters a better approach?